# Java code for finding element for attribute

Tags: java, string

I am writing a java code for finding element Ex.**food** for any attribute(attr)Ex.**description** in XML.

**What I have done**

I am taking first char of attr as start position and then checking if it equals to "<" .From this point I am looping to ignore white space,tab etc and proceed to append valid char till I find another white space,tab.But this is not working.It is supposed to find the first word after "<" and print that only .But its actually going till the end from the the point it find first char after "<"

**Note**:I cannot use XML parsers like DOM etc

```
XML
<breakfast_menu>
    <food name="Belgian Waffles" price="$5.95" discount="20"
        description="Two" calories="650" />
</breakfast_menu>


for (int k = start_position; k >= 0; k--) {
    char testChar = xmlInString.charAt(k);
    String temp = Character.toString(testChar);
    if ("<".equals(temp)) {
        System.out.println(k + "value of k");
        for (int j = k + 1; j >= 0; j++) {
            char appendChar = xmlInString.charAt(j);
            String temp1 = Character.toString(appendChar);
            if(!("".equals(temp1))) {
                System.out.println(j + "    " + appendChar);
            }


        }
    }

}
```

I made few changes now and its working as expected.i.e giving first word after "<". If you have any suggestion please let me know.

```
int k, j, l;

for (k = start_position; k >= 0; k--) {
    char testChar = xmlInString.charAt(k);
    String temp = Character.toString(testChar);
    if ("<".equals(temp)) {
        break;
    }

}
for (j = k + 1; j <= start_position; j++) {
    char appendChar = xmlInString.charAt(j);
    String temp1 = Character.toString(appendChar);
    if (!("".equals(temp1))) {
        break;

    }
}

for (l = j; l <= start_position; l++) {
    char appendChar1 = xmlInString.charAt(l);
    String temp2 = Character.toString(appendChar1);
    if (" ".equals(temp2)) {
        break;
    }

}

System.out.println(xmlInString.substring(j, l));
```

Comment: What's "not working"?  What specifically is not doing what it is supposed to do?  What is it supposed to do?  And what is it doing?  If you learn nothing else from this question, please learn how to ask good questions.

Comment: What output you are expecting from the above example?

Comment: @nhgrif and AJ I have added more information to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
String str = "<food name=\"Belgian Waffles\" price=\"$5.95\" discount=\"20\"\n" ;
       String res = str.substring(str.indexOf("<"), str.indexOf(" ", str.indexOf("<") + "<".length()) + " ".length());
        System.out.println(res);
```

**output**

```
<food
```

Comment: @A,J. This code is not specific to a particular XML.Also I had just posted a snippet of XML. In the complete XML there will be multiple "<" .Please see the latest code snippet I have pasted and let me know if you have suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner while loop `for (int j = k + 1; j >= 0; j++) {` is broken.  The condition `j >= 0` doesn't make sense - j only increments so how could it ever be < 0?  Instead you should be looking for the next space, tab, etc.

I don't think your solution is going to work, but that is what's wrong with the code you have posted and why it's running off the end.

Comment: Yes , you are right  I have corrected it as for (int j = k + 1; j <= start_position; j++)